# Very basic inheritance: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to learn c++ and I've stumbled upon a error while trying to figuring out inheritance.

Compiling: daughter.cpp
In file included from /home/jonas/kodning/testing/daughter.cpp:1:
/home/jonas/kodning/testing/daughter.h:6: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings

My files:
main.cpp:

```
#include "mother.h"
#include "daughter.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    mother mom;
    mom.saywhat();
    return 0;
}
```

mother.cpp:

```
#include "mother.h"
#include "daughter.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


mother::mother()
{
    //ctor
}


void mother::saywhat() {

    cout << "WHAAAAAAT" << endl;


}
```

mother.h:

```
#ifndef MOTHER_H
#define MOTHER_H


class mother
{
    public:
        mother();
        void saywhat();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // MOTHER_H
```

daughter.h:

```
#ifndef DAUGHTER_H
#define DAUGHTER_H


class daughter: public mother
{
    public:
        daughter();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // DAUGHTER_H
```

and daughter.cpp:

```
#include "daughter.h"
#include "mother.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


daughter::daughter()
{
    //ctor
}
```

What I want to do is to let daughter inherit everything public from the mother class (=saywhat()). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also you don't need to include `daughter.h` in either the `mother.h` or `mother.cpp`.
You have almost nailed the inheritance, make the changes that have been suggested and you should be good to go.

Comment: A C++ convention tip, as you say you're just learning--the first letter of class names are generally capitalized.  It's not a requirement, but you'll find it's a consistent coding convention.  Also, I see you've left positive comments on some answers below--please accept the answer which helped you the most! There should be a checkmark next to each answer, clicking it will accept it.  Thanks for contributing to StackOverflow!

Comment: Not for this question, but if you're trying to write a constructor or destructor you might have made a typo.

Answer (score 33):

You forgot to include `mother.h` here:

```
#ifndef DAUGHTER_H
#define DAUGHTER_H

#include "mother.h"  //<--- this line is added by me.    

class daughter: public mother
{
    public:
        daughter();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // DAUGHTER_H
```

You need to include this header,  because `daughter` is derived from `mother`. So the compiler needs to know the definition of `mother`.

Answer (score 16):

Not related to OP's issue, but for any other C++ learners stumbling upon this, I was getting this error for a different reason. If your parent class is templated, you need to specify the type name in the child class:

```cpp
#include "Parent.h"

template <typename ChildType>
class Child : public Parent<ChildType> { // <ChildType> is important here

};
```

Answer (score 12):

In daughter.cpp, switch the two lines of include. i.e.

```
#include "mother.h"
#include "daughter.h"
```

What happened was that the compiler is looking into the definition of class `daughter` and could not find the definition of the base class `mother`. So it's telling you that "I'm expecting the identifier `mother` in front of "{" in the line

```
class daughter: public mother {
```

to be a class, but I can't find it's definition!"

In `mother.cpp`, remove the inclusion of `daughter.h`. The compiler does not need to know the definition of `daughter.h`; i.e. class `mother` can be used without `daughter`. Adding the inclusion of `daughter.h` introduces unnecessary dependency between the class definitions.

On the other hand, it is always better IMHO to keep the inclusion of header in the definition of the class (.cpp) and not the declaration of the class (.h). This way it is less likely you need to resolve header inclusion nightmare when including headers that in turn include other headers which you don't have control. But many production code includes header in header. Both are correct, just need to be careful when you do that.

Answer (score 6):

Check that `#ifndef` and `#define` in your header file is unique.

```
#ifndef BASE_CLIENT_HANDLER_H
#define BASE_CLIENT_HANDLER_H

#include "Threads/Thread.h"

class BaseClientHandler : public threads::Thread {
public:
    bool isOn();
};
#endif //BASE_CLIENT_HANDLER_H
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

First off, you have include guards in implementation files. Remove them.

Second off, if you inherit from a class, you need to include the header where the class is defined.

Comment: Actually the guards are in `.h` file only. I think, she has a typo : the first `daughter.cpp` is supposed to be `daughter.h` actually.

Comment: @Nawaz yeah, I think you're right. I just saw cpp and include guards :)